# Binary Trees traversal comes out wrong in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I wrote this code to create rooted binary tree (Unbalanced) out of an adjacency matrix and traverse it inorder

```
typdef int key;
typdef struct Binode{
key nodenumber;
Binode* left, *right;
};
Binode* newNode(key nodenumber){
    Binode *node;
    node=(Binode*)malloc(sizeof(Binode));
    if (node==NULL){cout<<"Memory Allocation Failed"<<endl;return node;}
    node->nodenumber=nodenumber;
    node->right=NULL;
    node->left=NULL;
}

Binode *treeInsert(Binode *node, key nodedata){
    Binode* temp;
    temp=(Binode*)malloc(sizeof(Binode));
    if (temp==NULL){
        cout<<"Memory allocation failed"<<endl;
        return temp;
    }
    else{temp->nodenumber=nodedata;
        temp->right=temp->left=NULL;}

    if(node==NULL){
        node=temp;}
    else if (nodedata<node->nodenumber){
        node->left=treeInsert(node->left,nodedata);
    }

    else if (nodedata>node->nodenumber){
        node->right=treeInsert(node->right,nodedata);
    }
    return node;
}


Binode* Final=NULL;
Binode* treeToBin(key tRoot, key adjMsize)
{
    Final=newNode(tRoot);
    for(i=1;i<adjMsize;i++){
        if(i!=tRoot){
            Final=treeInsert(Final,i);
        }
    }
    return Final;
}
void inorder(Binode* i){
    if (i!=NULL){
        inorder(i->left);
        cout<<i->nodenumber<<"\t";
        inorder(i->right);
    }
}
```

but when it comes to the traverse it prints out the nodes in an incorrect order
it's expected to traverse it into `1 2 3 6 5 4` but it traverses it into `1 2 3 4 5 6`

Comment: isn't inorder 1 2 3 4 5 6 correct. What were the original inputs in the order they were inserted?

Comment: `error: ‘typdef’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘typeof’?` ... example doesn't compile ...

Comment: @OrenIshShalom Here is one that does compile: https://onlinegdb.com/HyoNqysAL

Comment: If I think the correct inorder is  `1 2 3 4 5 6`  because if you call `treeToBin(3,7)` you end up with a tree like `(1->2)<-3->(4->(5->6))` and if you call `treeToBin(1,7)` you end up with a tree like `1->(2->(3->(4->(5->6))))` because you are looping from 1 up to the max value and inserting them - if you had a loop from the root down to 1 and a loop from the root to the max you would end up with something different.

Comment: Regarding `node=(Binode*)malloc(sizeof(Binode));`, You can save yourself a whole bunch of typing with `node= new Binode();`. `new` knows how big things are and what type they are so you don't have to mess around with math and casting. Plus it also calls constructors, and this becomes very important as soon as you start using complicated types that need construction to be properly initialized and usable.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom
i'm using stdio.h library it uses the the typedefine function

Comment: @JerryJeremiah
for my project i enter the adjacency matrix to check if its simple tree or not then i choose the new root so for me i choose it to be `4`

Comment: @user4581301
Thank you for the information but I sadly have to use basic memory allocation function because this is what my professor wants it done by